# InstallShield and working directory

Tags: installshield

I have an InstallShield installer that during install time calls a C++/CLI DLL Me.dll which in turn calls a C# assembly; Microsoft.Foo.dll

When the the InstallShield installer attempts to load Microsoft.Foo.dll, I get a FileNotFoundException on it (i.e. could not load assembly).

Using fuslogvw.exe it tells me the assembly is trying to be loaded from the desktop, which is where I run the installer from.  The strange part is, inside the installer I call ChangeDirectory, and then verify that the SUPPORTDIR (i.e. temp where files are extracted) is indeed the current directory.  I also tried UseDLL on all of the assemblies, but that doesn't work either.

If I manually copy the assemblies to the desktop during install time, the installer works.

I must be missing a step.  How can I change InstallShields current working directory to SUPPORTDIR so it can properly find this assembly?

Comment: If the installer is calling the dll, then it needs to be in the same folder as the installer. Change Directory has nothing to do with the issue. You seem to have some sort of confusion between installer dlls and installed dlls. is Microsoft.foo.dll used in the installed application as well?

Comment: Yes, it is used in the installed application as well.  To be more specific, I call UseDLL(SUPPORTDIR ^ "Me.dll"); and then call a function in that DLL.  Me.dll is what references Microsoft.Foo.dll.

Comment: Needs to be in both places then unless you are going to try and use appdomain.assembly resolve. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff527268(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I played with this many ears ago (Blog: [Managed Code CAN Access the MSIHANDLE](http://blog.iswix.com/2006/12/managed-code-can-access-msihandle.html) ).  All of this is made obsolete by Windows Installer XML (WiX) Deployment Tools Foundation (DTF).   Read [Deployment Tools Foundation (DTF) Managed Custom Actions](http://blog.iswix.com/2008/05/deployment-tools-foundation-dtf-managed.html) for a primer.

Basically DTF builds custom action DLL's which appear as standard C/C++ custom actions to the Windows Installer.  They handle calling your C# code out of process as to not tattoo the MSIEXEC with a CLR version and make all your dependencies available in the current directory and marshall all the MSI API calls exposing it as a Session class to your code.  It really is the golden standard as described here: [Reasons DTF is Better](http://blog.iswix.com/2008/07/reasons-dtf-is-better.html)